# How to get the Path of mdb file from Project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I'm using *.mdb* file as database to save the information of forms designed in the c#. Currently, my .*mdb* file is in my project folder. Can any one help me how can I get the path of the file, so when project is moved for other systems it automatically consumes the path as I am finding no luck with below code

```
string filelocation = "~/DB/Practice.mdb"; 
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filelocation+"";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the whole point of question and correct me if I'm wrong. 
You want to set relative path to your database so if someone clone your project or pull it from Github wont have problems with connString?

The path of your database you can always find in your *app.config* file. Furthermore, your relative path should look like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=Database\databaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

, where *Database* is folder of your DBHelper class.

If you want, read more about converting absolute path to relative path 
[here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/954346c8-cbe8-448c-80d0-d3fc27796e9c/how-to-convert-absolute-file-path-to-relative-path-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)